# Python 2.7.12: How to combine two lists into a dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've searched google and the documentation, but I'm not able to find the answer for a (I guess) simple question. I have to corresponding lists.

```
NAMES = ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Cathy', 'Dan', 'Ed', 'Frank',
         'Gary', 'Helen', 'Irene', 'Jack', 'Kelly', 'Larry']

AGES = [20, 21, 18, 18, 19, 20, 20, 19, 19, 19, 22, 19]
```

These lists must become a dictionary where AGES is the key. I've written a function, however it overwrites the previous inserted value in the key..

```
def combine_lists(list_a, list_b):
    dictionary = dict()
    for i in range(len(list_a)):
        dictionary[list_a[i]] = list_b[i]
    return dictionary

print combine_lists(AGES, NAMES)
```

Executing the program gives me this:

```
{18: 'Dan', 19: 'Larry', 20: 'Gary', 21: 'Bob', 22: 'Kelly'}
```

What is the correct way to tackle this (simple) problem?

UPDATE:

What I want is that there are multiple values linked to a key, so that the key 18 gives me not only Dan, but Cathy as well.

Comment: You haven't said what you *want* the result to be.

Comment: I think you want the values in the dict to be lists (to which you append the names)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the entries to be lists...

```
from collections import defaultdict

age_name_dict = defaultdict(list)
for name, age in zip(NAMES, AGES):
    age_name_dict[age].append(name)
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use [zip function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=zip#zip)

it's, probably the most convenient and fast way.

Comment: OP wants a dict, not a list of tuples

Comment: @UnholySheep which could be used to construct a dict, but doesn't address OP's issue.